# firebase deploy hosting failure: retries exhausted after 6 attempts, with error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

ATTEMPTING TO EXECUTE:

```
$ firebase deploy --only hosting:prod --debug
```

where `prod` is a target that has been set up.

RESULTS:

The `--debug` output is quite lengthy. To summarize:

Starts with a bunch of standard messages, then gets to:

```
i  hosting[fretdrills]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[fretdrills]: found 811 files in dist/prod
[2023-09-16T19:48:02.629Z] [hosting] uploading with 200 concurrency
[2023-09-16T19:48:02.660Z] [hosting] hash cache [ZGlzdC9wcm9k] stored for 811 files
[2023-09-16T19:48:02.660Z] [hosting][hash queue][FINAL] {"max":3,"min":0,"avg":0.8722717265055857,"active":0,"complete":811,"success":811,"errored":0,"retried":0,"total":811,"elapsed":30}
[2023-09-16T19:48:02.660Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/239549909255/sites/fretdrills/versions/df6e759e6c14aa56:populateFiles [none]
[2023-09-16T19:48:02.661Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/239549909255/sites/fretdrills/versions/df6e759e6c14aa56:populateFiles {"files":{"/404.html":"0c227f4a7bd9e72cbc2039a3f19d34febc6ee5ac313870f887d9516e88f0d6f8","/appConfig.js":"b597af602adc56eca18829a2f6514398d49412f5ff2361595737099ee5fd4d8b","/favicon.ico":"9a3ef11e815cdbc3aa674b308730ae5144c9cfef57c36d4ea67c6f56bc687dd7",
```

All seems normal so far.

Then it gets to:

```
[2023-09-16T19:48:03.953Z] [hosting] uploads queued: 45
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
i  hosting: uploading new files [0/45] (0%)
[2023-09-16T19:48:34.320Z] [uploadQueue] Retrying task dfd970033c8ced499e5ef4ffc0f90b6545b3ad8e97a61c2e94d05b1e0e40ec22
[2023-09-16T19:48:34.321Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://upload-firebasehosting.googleapis.com/upload/sites/fretdrills/versions/df6e759e6c14aa56/files/dfd970033c8ced499e5ef4ffc0f90b6545b3ad8e97a61c2e94d05b1e0e40ec22 [none]
[2023-09-16T19:48:34.321Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://upload-firebasehosting.googleapis.com/upload/sites/fretdrills/versions/df6e759e6c14aa56/files/dfd970033c8ced499e5ef4ffc0f90b6545b3ad8e97a61c2e94d05b1e0e40ec22 [stream]
[2023-09-16T19:48:34.322Z] [uploadQueue] Retrying task cd6e3bd7b379bf6faef77e29a905d6d485669579be376091a4d3b1a930a877d3
[2023-09-16T19:48:34.322Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://upload-firebasehosting.googleapis.com/upload/sites/fretdrills/versions/df6e759e6c14aa56/files/cd6e3bd7b379bf6faef77e29a905d6d485669579be376091a4d3b1a930a877d3 [none]
[2023-09-16T19:48:34.322Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://upload-firebasehosting.googleapis.com/upload/sites/fretdrills/versions/df6e759e6c14aa56/files/cd6e3bd7b379bf6faef77e29a905d6d485669579be376091a4d3b1a930a877d3 [stream]
[2023-09-16T19:48:34.323Z] [uploadQueue] Retrying task 5dac034d5fe9bbf19660c053f3b6eb63d0c811148f0dd6a335de2deccf9906cb
[2023-09-16T19:48:34.324Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://upload-firebasehosting.googleapis.com/upload/sites/fretdrills/versions/df6e759e6c14aa56/files/5dac034d5fe9bbf19660c053f3b6eb63d0c811148f0dd6a335de2deccf9906cb [none]
[2023-09-16T19:48:34.324Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://upload-firebasehosting.googleapis.com/upload/sites/fretdrills/versions/df6e759e6c14aa56/files/5dac034d5fe9bbf19660c053f3b6eb63d0c811148f0dd6a335de2deccf9906cb [stream]
```

I'm starting to see a bunch of retry's, so that doesn't look good. This goes on for a while, then it gets to:

```
Task dfd970033c8ced499e5ef4ffc0f90b6545b3ad8e97a61c2e94d05b1e0e40ec22 failed: retries exhausted after 6 attempts, with error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
[2023-09-16T19:51:16.361Z] [hosting][upload queue][FINAL] {"max":0,"min":9999999999,"avg":0,"active":44,"complete":1,"success":0,"errored":1,"retried":214,"total":45,"elapsed":192446}
i  hosting: uploading new files [1/45] (2%)
Task cd6e3bd7b379bf6faef77e29a905d6d485669579be376091a4d3b1a930a877d3 failed: retries exhausted after 6 attempts, with error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
```

Again, doesn't seem to be looking too good. Then, it finally flags an error:

```
Error: Task dfd970033c8ced499e5ef4ffc0f90b6545b3ad8e97a61c2e94d05b1e0e40ec22 failed: retries exhausted after 6 attempts, with error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
```

BACKGROUND:

- `$ firebase --version` is `12.5.4`
- `$ node --version` is v18.16.1
- I have already removed the `.firebase` folder, as suggested in different SO threads (for different firebase deploy hosting errors)
- I've confirmed with `$ firebase login` that I am already logged-in
- I've confirmed that I'm using a fast internet connection
- restarted computer
- I've deleted everything in the prod folder, and replaced it with a single index.html, then deployed. It deployed fine, and I can go to the internet and see the index.html page. Then, I re-build everything for the prod folder, then deployed, and again it identifies that there are 45 new files, and gets stuck trying to upload them, resulting in the same error message. Now, the website is stuck on the single index.html page.
- I think the firebase is not spec'd to use with that node version. I reverted back to node v16.20.1, and still same problem.

QUESTION:

I haven't seen this error in the SO threads I've found regarding deployment of firebase hosting. Please help with suggestions on how I can fix this issue.

Best regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

I'm the OP, and I got this to work this morning.

- First, attempting a full deploy failed just as it did last night.
- I renamed the `prod` folder to `prod-copy`, and then started with an empty `prod` folder, then copied folders from the `prod-copy` folder into `prod` one by one, deploying each time.
- There was one folder that would not deploy (with the same errors above). It was 71MB with 55 files and 13 folders (some short video clips around 1.5MB each). I took each of the 13 folders, one by one, and copied them to `prod` and deployed each time. Doing this, I was able to deploy the entire site

I tested the upload speed of my internet and it was 6Mbps. Clearly, it is fast enough since I was able to upload all of the content. Something is not right with Firebase if it is necessary to break down uploads into smaller chunks. Especially, when GitHub has no problem with it ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I rerun firebase deploy --only hosting:site-name 10 times because it failed to upload the last 10 files. After each of the last 10 files it would give the failed error so I rerun the command and it would continue where it left off.